# Атрибут как переменная

Tags: атрибуты, переменные

Для класса selectpicker обычное присвоение через `.attr(attr_name, attr_value)` не работает.

Правильно работает через `$('#myselect').selectpicker({attr_name: attr_value})`.

`attr_name` - неизвестен, и получаю как переменную:

```
var attr_name = some_value;
```

Но! Как теперь использовать **ЗНАЧЕНИЕ** переменной в качестве атрибута?

Comment: @webpauk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибаюсь, единственный вариант это создать объект

```
var obj = {};
obj[attr_name] = some_value;
$('#myselect').selectpicker(obj);
```